# How to detect DB deadlocks caused by a single thread?

Tags: grails, transactions, database-deadlocks

With the following code anyone could easily get a DB deadlock within a *single* thread: just select an object twice in nested transactions using pessimistic LockMode.

```
def deadlockWithinSingleThread() {
    long id = ...
    Dog.withNewTransaction {
        getIt(id)
        Dog.withNewTransaction {
            getIt(id)
        }
    }
}

private Dog getIt(long id) {
    Dog.withCriteria(uniqueResult: true) {
        idEq id
        lockMode LockMode.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE
        maxResults 1
    }
}
```

Is there a way to detect such a simple kind of deadlocks? Alternatively, could I know (by request) if an object is locked by the same thread already?

Personally I'd prefer the 2nd `get()` to fail with an exception. I believe it's not a big trick to detect such situations for Spring, for example. However there is no a warning even.

Grails 2.2.0, PostgreSQL 9, Spring, Hibernate 3.2

Comment: Your example syntax is not valid. Can you provide working code you're using to demonstrate this?